# ADB without PC is it possible?

Tags: adb

Currently I don't have PC but I need to execute some commands via ADB. Is there any way to access ADB from other phone or anyhow without PC?

Comment: Install a terminal emulator

Comment: @beeshyams I need to execute "sh /data/data/me.piebridge.brevent/brevent.sh" to make [brevent](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.piebridge.brevent&referrer=utm_source%3Dgoogle%26utm_medium%3Dorganic%26utm_term%3Dbrevent+app&pcampaignid=APPU_1_P-xkWZK5OaSFgAbuqJXoDw) to work without root. Thanks for the thread but it won't work to me since neither of my phones support OTG, make an answer if you want.

Comment: @esQmo_ It won't work since command requires root or ADB to execute.

Comment: @beeshyams I lack root on this device, that's biggest pull-back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Limited commands for adb and fastboot are possible according to this [XDA](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2586472) post, that too on ARM architecture

Requirements :-

- Rooted android Tablet / Phone.
- OTG cable [ Make sure that your device supports OTG. (If not search your device's thread for OTG )]
- A root browser ( eg:- Root Explorer, ES file explorer)
- Terminal emulator

As indicated by OP in comments, this solution doesn't help as there is no OTG support nor is device rooted

Without root, to my limited knowledge, it is not possible